# How to combine two polarized or unpolarized signals

Tags: polarization

Is it possible to sum up two different polarized signals?

For example:

1. Polarized and Unpolarized
2. Linear and Circular

Answer (score 1):

For sure! The question is what you mean by "sum up" as the sum can sometimes be coherent or incoherent.

In the case of an incoherent sum, ie creating a statistical mixture of the two different signals, one uses either the [Stokes parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_parameters) $\mathbf{S}$ or the [coherency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_(waves)#Coherency_matrix) $\Phi$, which both contain the same information but arranged in different ways. With either of those things, an incoherent superposition is formed from
\begin{aligned}&\mathbf{S}_{\mathrm{total}}=p\mathbf{S}_{1}+(1-p)\mathbf{S}_{2},\\
&\Phi_{\mathrm{total}}=p\Phi_{1}+(1-p)\Phi_{2},\quad 0\leq p\leq 1.\end{aligned}

In the case of a coherent sum, i.e., superposing two waves, we use the [Jones vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jones_calculus#Jones_vector) formalism to transform a Jones vector $\mathbf{E}=\begin{pmatrix}E_{\mathrm{horizontal}}\\E_{\mathrm{vertical}}\end{pmatrix}$:
$$\mathbf{E}_{\mathrm{total}}=\alpha \mathbf{E}_{1}+\beta \mathbf{E}_{2},\quad |\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1.$$

What is the connection between these two approaches? The coherency matrix is expressed as the time-average or ensemble-average over Jones vectors
$$\Phi=\langle \mathbf{E}\mathbf{E}^\dagger\rangle,$$ where $\,^\dagger$ implies the  conjugate transpose, and the Stokes parameters are linear combinations of the elements of $\Phi$ [e.g., $S_0=\mathrm{Tr}(\Phi)$].